# Pyglet load resource with absolute path

Tags: python, pyglet

I'm very new to python, and I've researched this a bit, but the answers I found don't seem to work. I'm trying to load an mp3 file with pyglet with an absolutie path, but it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Apps\Python\lib\site-packages\pyglet\resource.py", line 624, in media
    location = self._index[name]
KeyError: 'C:/Users/Ruurd/Google Drive/Script/Python/music2.mp3'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ruurd/Desktop/playmus.py", line 3, in <module>
    music=pyglet.resource.media(path)
  File "C:\Apps\Python\lib\site-packages\pyglet\resource.py", line 634, in media
    raise ResourceNotFoundException(name)
pyglet.resource.ResourceNotFoundException: Resource "C:/Users/Ruurd/Google Drive/Script/Python/music2.mp3" was not found on the path.  Ensure that the filename has the correct captialisation.
```

When I use 'music2.mp3' as a path it works fine. Here is the not working code

```
import pyglet
path='C:/Users/Ruurd/Google Drive/Script/Python/music2.mp3'
music=pyglet.resource.media(path)
music.play()
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using:

```
music=pyglet.media.load(path)
```

instead of:

```
music=pyglet.resource.media(path)
```

Worked for me. =)

Comment: I was having the same issue as the author, that was the only answer that solved it. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyglet
from os.path import abspath, isfile

pyglet.options['audio'] = ('directsound', 'alsa', 'openal', 'silent')

path = abspath('C:/Users/Ruurd/Google Drive/Script/Python/music2.mp3')
if isfile(path):
    music = pyglet.resource.media(path)
    music.play()
```

Since you don't have your mp3 sourced anywhere i can't test this.
But it's generally a good idea to use `abspath` to be sure the syntax is correct and to use `isfile` to determine if the file exists on that path.

To get more control over the driver used, you can use `pyglet.options['audio']` to isntruct pyglet to use, for instance, `directsound`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work :(, isfile(path) is True, but music=pyglet.resource.media(path) still produces the error. I have found something else that sort of works though. If I use src=media.load(fname) and player=media.Player() player.queue(src) it only works with files that are in the same path as in the folder location, even though I am using absolute paths. I have no idea how to fix this..

Comment: @RuteNL It sounds to me like this is not actually an MP3 with proper encoding. I've had this issue before where a MP3 acts like a MP3 but has shitty encoding that isn't really standard. Most modern players (VLC etc) have learned to deal with these diverging formats while not so advanced and evolved players (such as GL libraries) have hard times coping. Try playing it through an audio-library/mixer or test with another file in the same spot with the same name. And also try `.vmw` which might work better since it's strange enough more commonly used.